# Silverstripe 3.2 re-usable blocks

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have created a new page type that needs something to break up the content. I have created a strapline block that i would like to use in 3 places on the page, however i want to create only 1 version of the strapline block and drive that content by dynamic data.

I have the following in Straplines.php

```
class Straplines extends DataObject{
    private static $db = array(
        'Title'=>'Text',
        'Content'=>'HTMLText',
        'SortOrder'=>'Int'
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Parent'=>'Page'
    );

    private static $default_sort = 'SortOrder';

    public function getCMSFields(){
            $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
            $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new HtmlEditorField('Content','Content'));
            $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('Title','Title'));
            return $fields;
    }
}
```

Then i add the cms fields to HomePage.php. I can add straplines no problem there and they all show up.
Then in HomePage.ss i have the following

```
<% include PricesBlock %>
<% include TourStraplineBlock %>
<% include QuickFacts %>
<% include TourStraplineBlock %>
```

But then I cannot figure out away in TourStraplineBlock to get separate content for each of these. Surely there must be away to parameterize the include or not have to create multiple templates. I'm quite new to Silverstripe dev and am finding it a tough process to create re-usable content.

Edit: This is the strapline.ss template that handles displaying.

```
<div class="strapline"> 
        <% loop Straplines %>
            $Content        
        <% end_loop%>
</div>
```

As you can probably guess, if i put this in twice it simply shows all the straplines. I want to do something like

```
<% include Strapline?id=1 %>
```

Then decode that in Strapline.ss and go from there.

Edit sorry yes its 3.2 not 3.0. I assumed that they were quite similar.

Comment: `private static $db` sounds definitly NOT like Silverstripe 3.0, more like 3.1 or 3.2. What Version of SS are you using? And could you show more code of HomePage.php and the include template you want to modify?

Comment: Made some edits as requested @wmk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Firesphere mentioned you could just create a function that you can call in your template and pass the object ID to it.

Put this function in your Page_Controller class or if you wish to access it only from the homepage, than put it in your HomePage_Controller class.

```
public function StraplineByID($id) {
  $strapline = Straplines::get()->byID($id);
  if($strapline) {
    return $strapline;
  }
}
```

In your template you can now use that:

```
<% if $StraplineByID(1) %>
  <% with $StraplineByID(1) %>
    $Title, $Content, $WhatEver or an include
  <% else %>
    Can't find a strapline with this ID
  <% end_with %>
<% end_if %>
```

If you want to identify the straplines not by id but by name (this would be more user friendly) you should create a new field called "Name" or something like that and use this instead of the id. But note the values in the Name field should be unique

```
public function StraplineByName($name) {
  $strapline = Straplines::get()->find('Name', $name);
  if($strapline) {
    return $strapline;
  }
}
```

and in your template

```
<% if $StraplineByName(prices) %>
  <% with $StraplineByName(prices) %>
    $Title, $Content, $WhatEver or an Include
  <% else %>
    Can't find a strapline with this Name
  <% end_with %>
<% end_if %>
```

The code is untested but it should work ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could make a function in page, which takes the argument as a literal, and returns the wished strapline. e.g.

```
<% $currentStrapline(1) %>
```

and a function in page,

```
public function currentStrapline($id) {
 // returns the wished strapline or null; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went with the other because I could follow exactly what was going on a little bit better, and i'm very new to silverstripe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to parametrise the include, and you almost had it:

```
<% include Strapline MyVar=$someVar, MyVar2=$someVar2 %>
```

Then in `Strapline.ss`:

```
<% if $MyVar == 1 %>
Say One
<% else_if $MyVar2 == 2 %>
Say Two
<% end_if %>
```